# WSO2 DOCTYPE not allowed calling REST Api

Tags: proxy, wso2, doctype, wso2-esb

i m working with this proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="PubMedDataProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="get"
                 uri-template="http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=omim&amp;Mdb=pubmed&amp;id=230900"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="MyLOg" expression="//eLinkResult/DbFrom/text()"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

i get this exception:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-05-21 13:45:34,838] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,142]
Message: DOCTYPE is not allowed
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder.processDocument(ApplicationXMLBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:239)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:556)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:198)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,142]
Message: DOCTYPE is not allowed
...
```

Calling the service in a normal REST client i get the XML result withouth any problem.

The issue occured when the proxy tries to parse the resulting xml. Indeed removing the Log mediator with the property inside the proxy returns the result correctly.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your proxy:

```
<parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below parameter to the axis2.xml file under the `<axisconfig name="AxisJava2.0">` also working.

```
<parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter>
```